# How to use one single excel file by more than 5 persons?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have five person say A,B,C,D and E. All of them needs to input data in one single file. At the end, the person F, do the sum total of inputed value and publish the result.

Simplified Version

- Person A open excel sheet and input some data in the given column
- Similar Person B,C,D and E open excel file and input there respective data in respective column.

  - Admin open and integrate all this data.

Now my problem is

1. How can I ensure that person A,B,C,D and E see there respective field only. I mean i don't want that A can see the data inputed by B and vice versa.
2. Ability to upload file against respective input in the cell and this file get saved in a particular folder suggested by admin

Please Note:
1. Input Value will be Numberic Only.
2. All the person will use the same server. So in that case, we can save the data on the same server. I think there will be no need of external server.

Anyone can help me in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the Admin must "open the file to integrate all this data" anyways, might it not be easier to have separate files for each person and then have the admin integrate them all in one file with a macro?

Comment: Share the Workbook is very much possible, but the way you want, needs Programming. Since you are thinking to impose lots of restrictions !!

Answer (score 1):

Excel isn't meant to operate this way.  However, databases operate this way.

You can create users names with passwords on a database and make it so the users can only see certain fields.

The number of users is only limited by the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Excel. Once a user accesses a .xls file, it will only open in 'read only' mode for all other users who open it.

The solution to your problem is to use Google Sheets. You will be able to set an administrator to your sheet, share the sheet out to other users, and limit editing to specific columns for specific invited users. All users will be able to edit the sheet simultaneously. You can also download the sheet as .xls for use in other systems if you so please.

Hope that helps.

Comment: There are ways to open an Excel document, in such a way, multiple computers can have it open.  However, you cannot hide content from one user, and display it to another, Excel was not designed with that use case in mind.